# Scikit-learn. Classify disordered jpgs

Tags: image, classification, scikit-learn

How would you approach the following problem: I have 5 classes of images (in total 500 images): car, house, trees, chair and face. Then I have a folder with 20 disordered images, which means I know they belong to one of the 5 classes but do not know yet to which one and I want my system to classify them according to the 5 controlled classes. I am using several extractors (hue,edge) to accomplish this task, but I am struggling to get a suitable classification approach. In particular some python libraries require to name the uncontrolled image folder in the same way as the class folder (e.g. /dir/controlled/car and /dir/uncontrolled/car) this simply is not feasible for my analysis. As far as I am looking for alternative approaches can you give some methodological advice/workaround within sklearn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it would be easier to use a labeled dataset such as [ImageNet](http://www.image-net.org/) to first train classifier on those 5 classes (+1 additional "misc" class that you would fill with random images not from those 5 classes).

Take as many examples as you can from image net to build your training set while keeping the classes approximately balanced. For instance imagenet has almost 8000 car pictures: http://www.image-net.org/synset?wnid=n02958343 but only around 1500 faces: http://www.image-net.org/synset?wnid=n02958343 . Some classifier might not work good in that case to subsampling the car class might yield better results in terms of f1 score. Unless you find another source of pictures of faces.

Once you find a set of parameters for feature extraction + classifier chain that yields good cross validated score on your ImageNet subset, retrain a model on that full subset and apply it to predict the labels of your own dataset.

Choose a classifier that give you confidence scores (e.g. with a method such as `predict_proba` or `decision_function`) and introspect the quality of classifications with the highest and lowest confidence scores:

- if all the highest classification are correct, add all the pictures above some safe threshold to a "staged two" training set that comprises the original imagenet subset and those new pictures.
- re-annotate manually the most offending mistakes in the lowest confidence predictions and add them to the "staged two" training set.

Iterate by retraining a new model on this enriched dataset until the classification algorithm is able to correctly annotate most of your pictures correctly.

BTW, don't change the parameters too much once you start annotating your data and iterating with the classifier to avoid overfitting. If you want to re-do parameter selection, you should do cross validation again.